# バッククオート記法について

Tags: common-lisp, lisp

```
    (defmacro define-class (class inst-vars class-vars &body methods)
(let ,class-vars
    (mapcar #'ensure-generic-fn ',(mapcar #'first methods))
    (defun ,class ,inst-vars
        #'(lambda (message)
            (case message
                ,@(mapcar #'make-clause methods))))))
```

をccl で評価したところ

```
    Comma not inside backquote
    While executing: CCL::SIGNAL-READER-ERROR, in process listener(1)
```

とおこられたのですが、どうしていけないのかわかりません。どなたかおしえてください

Answer (score 3, accepted):

バッククォートされた式の中でないと使えないということです。
つまり、

```
`(let ,class-vars
    ...
```

のようにする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。初歩的なミスでした。